# Supermirco IPMI KVM: remote connection without webbrowser

Tags: java, jnlp, ikvm, ipmitool, ipmi

I try to connect with the IPMI remote connection(KVM) without the use op the webbrowser or IPMIview tool. But so far no luck.

The first think that I did is launching the "jviewer.jnlp" with javaws. This file will be created by the IPMI website if you push the "Remote Connection" button. This solution works until the web session is closed. I try to replace the encrypted argument with the username and password. But somehow there is session id embedded.

jviewer.jnpl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://192.168.99.201/Java">
 <information>
    <title>JViewer</title>
    <vendor>American Megatrends, Inc.</vendor>
    <description kind="one-line">JViewer Console Redirection Application</description>
    <description kind="tooltip">JViewer Console Redirection Application</description>
    <description kind="short">
        JViewer enables a user to view the video display of managed server via KVM.  
        It also enables the user to redirect his local keyboard, mouse for managing the server remotely.
    </description>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
    <jar href="release/JViewer.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
    <nativelib href="release/Win32.jar"/>
</resources>    
<resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
       <j2se version="1.5+"/>
       <nativelib href="release/Win64.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux"  arch="x86">
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <nativelib href="release/Linux_x86_32.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux"  arch="i386">
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <nativelib href="release/Linux_x86_32.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <nativelib href="release/Linux_x86_64.jar"/>
</resources>    
<resources os="Linux" arch="amd64">
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <nativelib href="release/Linux_x86_64.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Mac OS X" arch="i386">
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <nativelib href="release/Mac32.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc>
    <argument>192.168.99.201</argument>
    <argument>5901</argument>
    <argument>Hnda9A159AwMjwnF</argument>
    <argument>0</argument>
    <argument>0</argument>
    <argument>5120</argument>
    <argument>5123</argument>
    <argument>511</argument>
    <argument>5900</argument>
    <argument>1</argument>
    <argument>EN</argument>
    <argument>HEWKovXQO2Fp7FEMho6LrM4kzTPFHPyB000</argument>

</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The argument username and password replacement will work if the jnlp is named as "launch.jnlp" Some Supermicro IPMI version will use a different structure.

Second I try to connect with the IPMIview tool version 2.9.32. That work so the connection is ok. Know I try the connect by using the jars of the IPMIview. Replace the host with the IPMI IP

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar iKVM.jar host ADMIN ADMIN null 5900 2623 2 0
```

This will open the remote connection but gives a "Connection failed" error.

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar JViewerX9.jar host ADMIN ADMIN
```

Also the same result: Connection failed
The connection failed comes with a warning box. On OK is closed the application

Some IPMI info:

```
# ipmitool mc info
Device ID                 : 32
Device Revision           : 1
Firmware Revision         : 2.4
IPMI Version              : 2.0
Manufacturer ID           : 47488
Manufacturer Name         : Unknown (0xB980)
Product ID                : 43707 (0xaabb)
Product Name              : Unknown (0xAABB)
Device Available          : yes
Provides Device SDRs      : no
Additional Device Support :
    Sensor Device
    SDR Repository Device
    SEL Device
    FRU Inventory Device
    IPMB Event Receiver
    IPMB Event Generator
    Chassis Device
Aux Firmware Rev Info     : 
    0x01
    0x00
    0x00
    0x00
```

A cold reset "ipmitool mc reset cold" also does not work.

I hope that someone knows what the argument mean for the jnlp file or the someone has a working solution for this problem

Edit:
I try the answer of Maxim Akristiniy and came up with the following code:

```
package com.thalesgroup.nl.perftools;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptResult;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie;

public class IpmiRemoteViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException,
            IOException {

        String username = "ADMIN";
    String password = "ADMIN";
    String ip = "192.168.99.150";

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);

    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webClient.getCookieManager().addCookie(
            new Cookie(ip, "WEBVAR_USERNAME", username));
    webClient.getCookieManager().addCookie(
            new Cookie(ip, "WEBVAR_PASSWORD", password));

    HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://" + ip);

    List<HtmlForm> forms = page1.getForms();

    if (!forms.isEmpty()) {

        HtmlForm form = forms.get(0);
        HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue(
                "Login").get(0);

        // username
        HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("T1");
        textField.setValueAttribute(username);

        // password
        HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("T2");
        textField2.setValueAttribute(password);

        HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(500);

        // Do it again
        form = page2.getForms().get(0);

        // username
        textField = form.getInputByName("T1");
        textField.setValueAttribute(username);

        // password
        textField2 = form.getInputByName("T2");
        textField2.setValueAttribute(password);

        ScriptResult scriptResult = page2.executeJavaScript("DoLogin();");

        // Print the index.html page
        System.out.println(scriptResult.getNewPage().toString());

        // Print the session id
        for (Cookie cookie : webClient.getCookieManager().getCookies()) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("SessionCookie")) {
                String sessionId = cookie.getValue();
                System.out.println("Session id = " + sessionId);
            }
        }

        // Download the jviewer.jnlp file
        Page page5 = webClient.getPage("http://" + ip
                + "/Java/jviewer.jnlp?EXTRNIP=" + ip + "&JNLPSTR=JViewer");
        WebResponse response = page5.getWebResponse();
        InputStream inputStream = response.getContentAsStream();

        writeToFile("viewer.jnlp", inputStream);
    }

}

protected static void writeToFile(String filename, InputStream inputStream) {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {

        File file = new File(filename);

        // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Only now it will write the login page in the viewer.jnlp file. Still no luck. I managed to read the index.html page that is behind the login page. But the session is closing very fast.

Answer (score 9):

Download the jviewer.jnlp file but first login.

```
#!/bin/sh

USER=ADMIN
PASS=ADMIN
HOST=192.168.99.150

COOKIE=`curl --data "WEBVAR_USERNAME=$USER&WEBVAR_PASSWORD=$PASS" http://$HOST/rpc/WEBSES/create.asp 2> /dev/null | grep SESSION_COOKIE | cut -d\' -f 4`
curl --cookie Cookie=SessionCookie=$COOKIE http://$HOST/Java/jviewer.jnlp -o $HOST.jviewer.jnlp
```

Then start the jviewer.jnlp file with javaws

Comment: This basic script will save me a LOT of time, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Supermicro uses American Megatrends' MegaRAC software, and jviewer is a part of it. MegaRAC offers a standalone jviewer application. You should be able to request it from Supermicro.

Answer (score 0):

you need connect to IPMI server and set cookie variables: WEBVAR_USERNAME, WEBVAR_PASSWORD
you will get in response in cookie variable SESSION_COOKIE
next download http://" + IP + "/Java/jviewer.jnlp?EXTRNIP=" + IP + "&JNLPSTR=JViewer 
to your jnlp

or use existing jnlp and replace received cookie in it with your cookie :

```
<argument>-webcookie</argument>
<argument>zIoAlbnWxQtHTIutR8wyeKxeo9nAVJF5000</argument>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. which url do you use to connect with the IPMI server. I tryed http://ip/page/html/login.html but no result. Can you explain more details how to retrieve the session id